# Prevent undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass for rendering nil User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

On my landing page, I'm attempting to list all instances of a Game model and the respective Assignment model associated with it. When a Game is created, an Assignment is created as well. The only thing passed into that Assignment is the game_id. The other 3 params are left nil. How do I display the games without getting a `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`. I figured this would be solved with `optional: true` set but I guess not.

I do understand in the _feed.html.erb file it's returning that error because it's expecting a user object so would I just need to bake some logic into it to prevent that? In the end, if either `center_referee`,`assistant_referee_1`, and/or `assistant_referee_2` hasn't been set yet, I need it to display blank

```
_feed.html.erb

<div>
    <% @games.each do | game | %>
            <p ><%= game.home_team %> vs <%= game.away_team %></p>
            <p >Center Referee: <%= game.assignment.center_referee.name %></p>
            <p >AR1: <%= game.assignment.assistant_referee_1.name %></p>
            <p >AR2: <%= game.assignment.assistant_referee_2.name %></p>
            <br></br>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

```
models/game.rb

class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :assignment, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :assignment

    after_save :create_assignment

    def create_assignment
        Assignment.create(game_id: id)
    end
end
```

```
models/assignment.rb

class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game

    belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: 'User', optional: true
    belongs_to :assistant_referee_1, class_name: 'User', optional: true
    belongs_to :assistant_referee_2, class_name: 'User', optional: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :game    
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&`

```rb
game.assignment.center_referee&.name
```

It's a safe navigation operator, introduced in Ruby 2.3.0. And you may find the [docs here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator).

And if you wanna read more about it, you can get it [here](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) (sent by [@crodev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10249627/crodev))

Comment: Can you explain what that did? It works but I'd like to understand it.

Comment: @wayoh22 It's called a safe navigation operator in Ruby. I found this [article](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). Take a look at it.

Comment: Sure, I will add it to my answer